# Shadow of a ripple?

Tags: visible-light

Suppose a stone is thrown into a pool of crystal clear water and its a bright sunshiny morning. You can observe a shadow of the wave in the bottom of the pool. Why does this happen? Is it due to superposition of light or some other thing?

Comment: It's not so much a shadow as it is a bending of light away from a certain point.

Comment: yeah ,but is the bending effect of superposition of light by waves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually think of the ripple as a travelling lens.

If you take a radial cross section through the ripple, it'll have a curved profile. Now just like a magnifying glass causes a bright spot in the middle of where you focus incoming light, it also causes a darker region around it.

This is what you're seeing on the bottom of the pool: The band of focussed (or unfocussed, depending on depth) light caused by the lens-like nature of the ripple wave.

Comment: I was also wondering about the contribution of varying reflectivity from the changing angle of incidence at the water surface.  Hmmmmm - maybe I should calculate that some time...

Answer (score 0):

The dark part of the shadow is the umbra, and the part that is a little lighter is the penumbra. They can be experienced on Earth, but more readily in space, such as during a solar eclipse, when the Moon moves in front of the Sun and leaves a shadow on Earth.

Comment: The ripple image is due to refraction (& maybe reflection), it's not actually a shadow.

Comment: I agree with  @PM2Ring